# "Proof" of equivalence of norm?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I am currently studying linear algebra and came across equivalence of norm.

Let $\|\cdot\|_a$, and $\|\cdot\|_b$ be two norms defined on a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb R$ of finite dimensions. Let $\{e^1, \cdots, e^n\}$ be basis of $V$. I want to find $c_1, c_2 >0$ such that $c_1\|\cdot\|_a \leq \| \cdot\|_b \leq c_2\|\cdot\|_a$.

Let $v \in V = \sum v^ie^i$, where $v^i \in \mathbb R$. Then by triangular inequality,
$\|v\|_b \leq \sum |v^i|\|e^i\|_b$, and $\|v\|_a \leq \sum |v^i|\|e^i\|_a$. Choose $c_1>0$ sufficiently small so that $c_1\|e^i\|_a \leq \|e^i\|_b$ for every $i = 1, \cdots, n$. Simiarly, choose $c_2>0$ sufficiently large that $\|e^i\|_b \leq c_2\|e^i\|_a$ for every $i$. Then,

$c_1\|v\|_a \leq \sum c_1|v^i| \|e^i\|_a \leq \sum |v^i| \|e^i\|_b = \|v\|_b$.
Similarly, $\|v\|_b \leq c_2\|v\|_a$. Hence, equivalence of norm is achieved.

I am aware that there are millions of posts about equivalence of norm floating around in google. However, I believe there are a lot of unnecessary steps involved; some proofs involve establishing an equivalence between any norm $\|\cdot\|_a$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$, and finding maximum of norm in $S^n$, i.e. finding $C = \max_{v \in S^n} \|v\|_a$. However, my argument does not involve the equivalence of norm between $\|\cdot\|_a$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$ nor use maximum of norm on a unit sphere.

If I am missing anything, I would like to know where my argument above breaks down.

-------closed--------

Comment: How did you get $\Sigma |v^i|\cdot ||e^i||_b=||v||_b$ in the third paragraph?

Comment: When you say "choose $c_1>0$ sufficiently small so that $c_1||e^i||_a \leq ||e^i||_b$", can you give, explicitly, the value of $c_1$?

Comment: @DavidCheng ok. I see the error. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @azif00 As David pointed out, my argument is flawed. However, I chose $c_1$ as follows: for each $i$, I let $b_i>0$ such that $b_i||e^i||_a \leq ||e^i||_b$. Let $c_1 = min\{b_i\}$.

Comment: You may be able to fix this using the convexity of the unit "spheres". However I think this will be equivalent to showing that the unit sphere in each norm has a maximum value in the other norm.